# Looking for example of a surjective homomorphism on $(\mathbb R,+)$ which is not an automorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, analysis

Give example of a surjective function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) , \forall x,y \in \mathbb R$ but $f$ is not injective . I think I have to do something with basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ , but am not sure ; Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B=\{e_\lambda\mid\lambda\in \Lambda\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $\mathbb{R}$. It will be helpful for you to pick out a countable-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{R}$ with basis $B'=\{f_1,f_2,\ldots\}$ where $f_i=e_\lambda$ for some lambda and $f_i\neq f_j$ for all $i\neq j$. Can you find a surjective $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map $V\to V$ which is not injective (hint: first find a surjective function $B'\to B'$ which is not injective)? If you can, can you extend this linear map to the whole of $\mathbb{R}$?